# Sharepoint Online Search bar disappears when Quick launch is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online

Trying to figure out a way to display Search box in a SharePoint Online team site with the quick launch disabled.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Much appreciated.

Here is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvgsy.png)

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? If yes, please remember to accept the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the search box at the top of the page?

Whether you want to achieve this in the modern page or classic page?

In my SharePoint Online modern page, when I go to site settings -> Navigation Elements -> Disable quick Launch, the search box also display.

And in the SharePoint classic page, by default, there is no search box at the top of the page.
[image]

Comment: Can I know if this is a team site with O365 Group?

Comment: Yes, it is a team site with office 365 group.